# Filtering of data table yields unexpected results

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to filter a data table and seemingly two equivalent methods yield different results. Unfortunately, I cannot share the data and I am also not able to replicate my issue with a simple example. Below I provide the code for each of the methods. In the first method we select an element from a vector to filter a datatable. The result is a non-empty data table. However, when I store the first element of that vector in a separate filter and try to filter using that variable, the result is an empty table. What could be the reason? The code provided is exactly the code that I ran.

```
# Method 1

dataSet[FieldLabel == stringVector[1]] # stringVector[1] is something like "XDE 01.1 - YYYY QX BBBB 
Probability (incl. XXX) - changed.xlsm"

# Method 2

template <- stringVector[1]
dataSet[FieldLabel == template]
```

Comment: Is `stringVector` a character vector? What does `str(stringVector)` return?

Comment: Do you happen to have a column named `template` in `dataSet`?

Comment: If yes, consider `dataSet[FieldLabel == get("template", parent.frame())]` or `setkey(dataSet, FieldLabel) ; dataSet[template]`

Comment: @Aurele, no `'templates' %in% names(dataSet)` yields `FALSE`

Comment: @Roland, `str(stringVector)` returns `chr [1:16] "XDE 01.1 - YYYY QX BBBB 
Probability (incl. XXX) - changed.xlsm" ...`

Comment: What about `'template' %in% names(dataSet)`?

Comment: @Roland, omg that's it! What a relief! So `template` is a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurele, found the issue the variable `template` is a column in `dataSet`. I simply renamed the variable `template` to avoid the issue.